# Error using pickle.load on sklearn VotingClassifier

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, pickle

I'm trying to store a trained ML model using pickle.dump(ML_model) to use it on a website built with django. When doing that with e.g. logistic regression everything works fine. However when doing that with the sklearn VotingClassifier I get the following error when using pickle.load(my_stored_voting_classifier):

```
ModuleNotFoundError at ...
No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.voting'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/....
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.voting'
Exception Location: ...views.py in ...
Python Executable:  ...python
Python Version: 3.6.8
```

#### Store the model:

where eclf is the classifier

```
model_name = "votingensemble"
path = f'/.../.../{model_name}'
with open(path, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(eclf, file)
```

#### Load the model:

```
path = '/.../.../votingensemble'
with open(path, 'rb') as model:
     ml_model = pickle.load(model)
```

Comment: Are you missing a colon : in the second code block. I presume it’s just a typo here :)

Comment: this was just a typo in this post. The error is still appearing

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. Pickling and unpickling a VC model works fine for me. Python 3.6, jupyter notebook and ipython console. Did you import the votingclassifier into the namespace where you're trying to load the model? Can you edit your question to include the full error traceback?

Comment: Yes, I have imported the voting classifier. Have you tried running your unpickled VC model? Does it work? I'm a bit confused because the error is `No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.voting" `. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think there is no module called sklearn.ensemble.voting.

Comment: I am facing same issue